# Inequality with Arc Length

Tags: real-analysis, problem-solving

Define $L:=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{(x'(t))^2+(y'(t))^2} dt$.

Show $L\geq|x(1)-x(0)|$.

I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{(x'(t))^2+(y'(t))^2} dt \ge \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{(x'(t))^2} dt = \int_{0}^{1} \lvert x'(t) \rvert dt
$$

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you replace the $y'(t)$ term by $0?$